# Mysql error: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'world'

Tags: java, mysql

I've tried the last 40 minutes to find out of this bug. The error `Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value` apparently means: `comparing a string column with an integer, because they both get converted to double for the comparison`.

Here is my table:

```
this.sql.query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `back_locations` ("
                    + "`playerID` INT(11) NOT NULL, "
                    + "`world` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "
                    + "`x` INT(11) DEFAULT 0, "
                    + "`y` INT(11) DEFAULT 0, "
                    + "`z` INT(11) DEFAULT 0 )");
```

And here is the method with the error (The line with the UPDATE query):

```
public void DB_setBackLocation( Location loc, int playerID )
{
    try 
    {
        String world = loc.getWorld().getName();
        int x = (int)(loc.getBlockX());
        int y = (int)(loc.getBlockY());
        int z = (int)(loc.getBlockZ());

        ResultSet rs = sql.query( "SELECT * FROM back_locations WHERE playerID = " + playerID + "" );

        if( rs != null && rs.next() )
        {
            //The next line is the line with an error
            sql.query( "UPDATE back_locations SET world=\"" + world + "\" AND x=" + x + " AND y=" + y + " AND z=" + z + " WHERE playerID=" + playerID + "" );
        }
        else
        {
            sql.insert("back_locations", 
                    new Object[]{ "playerID", "world", "x", "y", "z"}, 
                    new Object[]{ playerID, world, x, y, z});
        }
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And my error:
[image: The error]

Thank you for answer in advance.

Best regards Alexander

EDIT 1:

Here is the line printed

[image: debug message]

Comment: What if you store the query in a string and print it (for debugging) before executing?

Comment: I've added the outprint in the question

Comment: I'm not sure but is it valid to use AND as a column separator in UPDATE statement?

Comment: I have always used it. It works like a charm. I guess I have a syntax error of some sort, but cant fint it :(

And the error makes no sense to me.

Comment: try using single quote values in `UPDATE back_locations SET world=\""`

Comment: Try replacing the `AND`s with commas.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct! I put `,` in stead of `AND` and it works like it should again. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subsequent `AND`s are causing your string to be evaluated as a boolean, which is causing the warning you're seeing. To fix it, simply correct the syntax by replacing your `AND`s with commas.

Answer (score 1):

Your [update](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Update_%28SQL%29) syntax is incorrect,

```
"UPDATE back_locations SET world=\"" + world + "\" AND x=" 
    + x + " AND y=" + y + " AND z=" + z + " WHERE playerID=" + playerID + ""
```

Looks like it should be,

```
"UPDATE back_locations SET world='" + world + "', x=" 
    + x + ", y=" + y + ", z=" + z + " WHERE playerID=" + playerID
```

I would really recommend you use bind parameters with a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).